# System.InvalidOperationException : Unknown connection string parameter '

Tags: entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unknown connection string parameter

I have a class `ServiceTest` which is inherited from `DbContext` and I have a constructor of the same class which inherits the connection like below using EF 6

```
public ServiceTest() : base("sampleconnectionstring")
{
   // some test code 
}
```

I want to pass connection string since I have multiple db context which are used by the same application.

Comment: Is `"sampleconnectionstring"` the actual connection string value you use or is it just a placeholder for this question? And what exactly is `base` (the actual type) in your code?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: Also are you using EF 6 or EF Core 6? Those are two completely different products.

Comment: i am using EF 6